# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_tables2'

Tags: django

I am trying to use Django-tables2, but my project can't find this module.

Firstly, I installed it without a problem.

```
(acct) C:\Users\tsjee_000\dev\acct\src>pip install django-tables2
Requirement already satisfied: django-tables2 in c:\users\tsjee_000\dev\acct\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: Django>=1.11 in c:\users\tsjee_000\dev\acct\lib\site-packages (from django-tables2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\tsjee_000\dev\acct\lib\site-packages (from Django>=1.11->django-tables2)
```

Secondly, I added this to 'INSTALLED_APPS' in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_tables2',

    'clients',
    'companies',
    'report',
]
```

Thirdly, views.py and html templates are updated according to the tutorial.

But when I run my project it doesn't work because of the error,

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_tables2'

I think this error happens in settings.py.

FYR, 'django_tables2'module can be imported correctly in the shell mode.

Comment: Did you also complete this step: `make sure that 'django.template.context_processors.request' is added to the context_processors in your template setting OPTIONS.`?

Comment: Yes, I did.
'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },

Comment: You have installed the package to a virtualenv, as far as I can see. Is the virtualenv activated before you try to run it?

Comment: Yes, this project is under virtualenv, and it is activated.

Comment: Thanks, melwill !
It works when I try 'runserver' on the activated venv prompt.

Comment: Would appreciate if you marked my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it has been installed correctly, are you sure you have activated your virtualenv? The supplied output above indicates you are using a virtualenv called `acct`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
pip install django_tables2
```

Comment: pip install django-tables2